# How to initialise object with private setters?

Tags: c#

When I use the following:

```
static public string myString { get; private set; }
```

How can I set value at the same time? Problem is my class is static, so right at it's declaration, I need to make sure it has a value.

Normally I use it with non static class, so I set the value in the class constructors.

Comment: You could set it in your static constructor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid only in C# 6.0. C# 6.0 adds this syntax:

```
static public string myString { get; private set; } = "Hello";
```

Unless you plan to set `myString` at some later time in your program, consider making the property read-only (that's another new feature of C# 6.0):

```
static public string myString { get; } = "Hello";
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I realise I cannot do that in my version, so I use Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov answer. Yours is really helping too. If I could I'd mark them both as answer.

Comment: @MaximeJoyal don't you worry. The answers are exactly the same. C#6 adds the syntax shortcut for initializing your variables inside of the static constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Use static constructor ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)) to initialize your properties.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
static public string myString { get; private set; } = "default value";
```

Comment: Though Correct but possible in C#6. Probably you should mentioned the same in answer.

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, I know. I didn't remember offhand which version it was, and dasblinkenlight added his more complete answer in the mean time, so I didn't bother checking. I just upvoted his answer instead :)